# Typing "git pull", the prompt give the error hint about vim

Tags: git, vim

Every time i type `git pull` and there are some changes in the repo, the bash will return error like following pic.
[image]

Cause i just copy a config of vim from Internet and i don't know config about vim config. How can i fix it.

Comment: Marginally related, but here's a very, very common advice around [tag:vim] is - never copy Vim configuration from Internet. Instead, start with fresh config, and copy in one line (or block) at a time as you look at the help, Internet, or whatever resources, understand what it does and why you want it. Unconfigured Vim is already very powerful; putting new things in without understanding leaves you unable to diagnose issues.

Answer (score 1):

just try:

```
git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim
```

or:

```
git config --global core.editor $(which vim)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems links to a python installation, assuming a Mac OS environment.
See [Valloric/YouCompleteMe issue 3216](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/3216) (mentioned [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2218#issuecomment-439920853)):

> I fixed the issue for myself, running all these commands (I use `pathogen.vim` so `YouCompleteMe` is installed in `~/.vim/bundle`):
>
> ```
> brew install vim
> cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
> python install.py
> ```
>
> My `python --version` is
>
> Python 2.7.15
>
> and I think it's installed with homebrew:
>
> ```
> $ which python
> /usr/local/bin/python
> ```

There is also a [recent macvim regression](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/803#issuecomment-445767290). See [PR 812](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/pull/812) as a fix example.